# Creating Excel file from array using php and symfony

Tags: php, arrays, excel, symfony

I'm trying to export an array as XLS file using PHP and symfony as shown by the code below. Once the XLS file created, I can only get the last row of the array, and it's displayed in the first line of my file. It seems that the "lignes" variable is not incremented. I can't figure out what's wrong, can anyone help with that?

```
  foreach ($adresses as $ad ){

            $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A' . $lignes, $ad->getId());
            $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('E' . $lignes, $ad->getTypeVoie());
            $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('F' . $lignes, $ad->getVoie());
            $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('G' . $lignes, $ad->getTypeQuartier());
            $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('H' . $lignes, $ad->getQuartier());
            $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('I' . $lignes, $ad->getCodePostale());
            $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('K' . $lignes, $ad->getPays());
            $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('J' . $lignes, $ad->getVille());
            $lignes++;

        }
        $writer = $this->get('phpexcel')->createWriter($phpExcelObject, 'Excel2007');
        $writer->save($fichier->getWebPathOut() );
```

Comment: `$lignes++` inside your loop.... that's the row number, and you never change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try something like:

```
    $lignes = 1;
    $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    foreach ($adresses as $ad ){
            $phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()
            ->setCellValue('A' . $lignes, $ad->getId())
            ->setCellValue('E' . $lignes, $ad->getTypeVoie())
            ->setCellValue('F' . $lignes, $ad->getVoie())
            ->setCellValue('G' . $lignes, $ad->getTypeQuartier())
            ->setCellValue('H' . $lignes, $ad->getQuartier())
            ->setCellValue('I' . $lignes, $ad->getCodePostale())
            ->setCellValue('K' . $lignes, $ad->getPays())
            ->setCellValue('J' . $lignes, $ad->getVille())
            $lignes++;

        }
        $writer = $this->get('phpexcel')->createWriter($phpExcelObject, 'Excel2007');
        $writer->save($fichier->getWebPathOut() );
```

Comment: Actually I start it at 2 `$lignes=2`

Answer (score 3):

The code could be like below. This is working code. Hope you got your answere here in this code. This functionality uses php excel `"phpoffice/phpexcel": "^1.8"`.

```
public function downloadAction(Request $request)
{
    $phoneListId = $request->get('phonelist_id');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $phoneList = $em->getRepository(PhoneList::class)->find($phoneListId);

    $phoneNumbers = $phoneList->getPhoneNumbers();

    // ask the service for a Excel5
    $phpExcelObject = $this->get('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject();

    $phpExcelObject->getProperties()->setCreator("liuggio")
        ->setTitle($phoneList->getTitle())
        ->setSubject($phoneList->getTitle());

    $sheet = $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Name');
    $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Number');
    $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Phone Number');
    $sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'Designation');
    $sheet->setCellValue('E1', 'Office');

    $counter = 2;
    foreach ($phoneNumbers as $phoneNumber) {
        $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $counter, $phoneNumber->getName());
        $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $counter, $phoneNumber->getNumber());
        $sheet->setCellValue('C' . $counter, $phoneNumber->getPhoneNumber());
        $sheet->setCellValue('D' . $counter, $phoneNumber->getDesignation());
        $sheet->setCellValue('E' . $counter, $phoneNumber->getOffice());
        $counter++;
    }

    $phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($phoneList->getTitle());

    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    // create the writer
    $writer = $this->get('phpexcel')->createWriter($phpExcelObject, 'Excel5');
    // create the response
    $response = $this->get('phpexcel')->createStreamedResponse($writer);
    // adding headers
    $dispositionHeader = $response->headers->makeDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        $phoneList->getTitle() . '.xls'
    );
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
    $response->headers->set('Pragma', 'public');
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'maxage=1');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $dispositionHeader);

    return $response;
}
```