# Download PhpSpreadsheet file without save it before

Tags: php-7, symfony4, phpspreadsheet

I'm using [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) to generate an Excel file in Symfony 4. My code is:

```php
$spreadsheet = $this->generateExcel($content);

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$filename = "myFile.xlsx";
$writer->save($filename); // LINE I WANT TO AVOID
$response = new BinaryFileResponse($filename);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
$response->setContentDisposition(
    ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
    $filename
);
```

But I don't want to save the file and then read it to return to the user. I would like to download Excel content directly. Is there a way to do It?

I've searched how to generate a stream of the content (as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39247345) says) but I hadn't success.

Thanks in advance and sorry about my English

Answer (score 59, accepted):

As I understand you are generating the content in your code.
You can [stream the response in Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#streaming-a-response) and configure PhpSpreadsheet Writer to  save to 'php://output' (see here the official doc [Redirect output to a client's web browser](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#redirect-output-to-a-clients-web-browser)).

Here is an working example using Symfony 4.1 and Phpspreadsheet 1.3:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer as Writer;

class TestController extends Controller
{


    /**
     * @Route("/save")
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

        $writer = new Writer\Xls($spreadsheet);

        $response =  new StreamedResponse(
            function () use ($writer) {
                $writer->save('php://output');
            }
        );
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="ExportScan.xls"');
        $response->headers->set('Cache-Control','max-age=0');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth mention that if you're calling `index()` via an API, then the file is returned as data in the response, and not as a direct download — at least that's what's happening for me.

Comment: If you are download ing the file is it good idea to use php://output, is ot good for performance ?

Comment: Your writing data before streaming, imagine you have huge sql data that should iterated  ?

Answer (score 4):

This is the solution for Laravel. But it still uses `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse` in the end.

```
        $contentDisposition = 'attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"';
        $contentType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';

        $response = response()->streamDownload(function () use ($spreadsheet) {
            $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
            $writer->save('php://output');
        });
        $response->setStatusCode(200);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', $contentType);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $contentDisposition);
```

Then you can send the response directly as a stream with

```
$response->send();
```

or just return it back in the controller

```
return $response;
```